# Adding addresses to a model via django's admin.py and with django-address

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I am having a problem with my django app. I am trying to add a model of restaurants that has an address field, and I am using [django-address](https://pypi.org/project/django-address/) to help me with this. So, my Restaurant model looks like this:

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    address = AddressField(on_delete = models.CASCADE, default = None)
```

However, when I go to add a specific restaurant using admin.py, it doesn't let me. As shown in the screenshot below, I type in one character and then it does not allow me to edit it:

[image: Screenshot of admin.py]

I have been able to add specific addresses themselves, but I can't figure out how to connect these addresses to a specific restaurant. Does anyone have any ideas about how to fix this? Or, does anyone have any nice work-arounds where I can add some specific restaurants without using admin.py?